# Get activity custom title view

Tags: android

In my activity I use custom title feature:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.myactivitylayout);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.myactivitytitle);
```

This works well, I can see *myactivitytitle.xml* elements in title of activity.

Now, I need to edit programatically elements of *myactivitytitle.xml* to do something like this:

```
View titleView = getTitleView();//This is the function I need
EditText et = titleView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
et.setText(...
```

How I can get the view of the title to access its elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my `main_activity.java`. In my activity I use custom title (`R.layout.mytitle`). there is a `TextView` in my title. i can get this `TextView` and i can set it's text with this code.

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
    TextView krdTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Kredi);
    krdTxt.setText("Faturalı Abone ");
```